# Does clang support "-fprofile-generate" and "-fprofile-use"?

Tags: c++, clang, profile

I am using 3.5 and it doesn't seem to be in there... Am I missing something?

For example, with GCC I can compile a program like this:

```
gcc -fprofile-generate main.cpp
```

...then I run the program, and after it exits (gracefully) it will generate a set of files (extensions are .gcda I think).  These files contain branching results that can be used to do profile-based optimization like this:

```
gcc -fprofile-use main.cpp
```

Is there a similar feature in Clang that I have overlooked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Profiling with Instrumentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#profiling-with-instrumentation) section of Clang manual mentions the flags `-fprofile-instr-generate` and `-fprofile-instr-use` with almost the same meaning.